# how to get the last child of the parent node in Tree View using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have created tree view in asp.net.I want to get the last child node of the current selected Parent Node.

Please Guide me get out of this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code to get the last child node in the current selected node:

```
     TreeNode t=TreeView1.SelectedNode.ChildNodes[TreeView1.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1];
```

Hope this helped you.